# Problems with files downloading from Google Drive

Tags: android, google-drive-api

Last time I am getting the problem with files downloading from Google Drive (though it was working properly before).

http://screencast.com/t/peczgkmftRG

It even does not run in Activity, intended for data processing. Then the following excerption was displayed in logs:

```
java.io.IOException: Network Error Could not update entry https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full/file%3A0B2rp3fzjxgqkMi1mSFJIMFVSN28: Received 500 status code: <errors xmlns='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005'><error><domain>GData</domain><code>ServiceException</code><internalReason>An unknown error occurred.</internalReason></error></errors>
```

I decided to make an application like this for testing, using [this tutorial](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/java-client#set_mime_types_in_the_app_manifest); however, I’ve got the same as a result. Maybe someone had such experience before? Please steer me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the docsList api which was deprecated a few days ago. Migrate the code to the drive api. Lots of questions about it on s.o. search for them and in the official google documentation.